# Google Analytics on React app doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, react-router, create-react-app, react-router-dom

I hosted my portfolio (which is still under development) on github pages. It's just a web app with static content. And I needed to add Google Analytics to my portfolio and get the number of visits (mainly to get familiar with the process). I found out [react-ga](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga) module which can be used to configure Google Analytics on React Apps (which created using create-react-app).

And followed [this](https://web-design-weekly.com/2016/07/08/adding-google-analytics-react-application/) tutorial and configured it and hosted. And I checked the site with **test traffic** but Google Analytics dashboard doesn't update. What maybe the case ? It should work according to the tutorial. As I'm new to *Google Analytics* it's hard for me to figure out the issue.

This is my **App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import HeaderList from "./components/Header";
import "./App.css";
import { Layout } from "antd";
import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import createHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory";
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
import Keys from './config/keys';

import AboutMe from "./components/AboutMe";
import Skills from "./components/Skills";
import Contact from "./components/Contact";
import Projects from "./components/Projects";

const { Content } = Layout;
ReactGA.initialize(Keys.GOOGLE_TRACKING_ID); //Unique Google Analytics tracking number

function fireTracking() {
  ReactGA.pageview(window.location.hash);
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router onUpdate={fireTracking} history={createHistory({ basename: process.env.PUBLIC_URL })}>
        <div>
          <Layout>
            <HeaderList />
            <Content className="Content">
              <div className="RouteContent">
                <Switch>
                  <Route exact path="/" component={AboutMe} />
                  <Route path="/skills" component={Skills} />
                  <Route path="/projects" component={Projects} />
                  <Route path="/Contact" component={Contact} />
                </Switch>
              </div>
            </Content>
          </Layout>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: what version of react-router are you using?

Comment: version 4 . `"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"`

Comment: @ztadic91 why did you remove the answer you posted ? Any help regarding this issue ?

Answer (score 11):

### React v16.8 or higher

The pageviews can be generated in a `useEffect` function; `withRouter` is used to inject props on route changes:

```js
import React, { useEffect }          from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactGA                       from 'react-ga';
import Keys                          from './config/keys';

//Unique Google Analytics tracking number
ReactGA.initialize(Keys.GOOGLE_TRACKING_ID); 

const App = () => {

    useEffect( () => {

        // This line will trigger on a route change
        ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search); 

    });

    return (/* Code here */);

}

export default withRouter(App);
```

### Prior to React v16.8

You need to generate a pageview in componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:

```
componentDidMount  = () => ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
componentDidUpdate = () => ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
```

So, final code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import HeaderList from "./components/Header";
import "./App.css";
import { Layout } from "antd";
import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import createHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory";
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
import Keys from './config/keys';

import AboutMe from "./components/AboutMe";
import Skills from "./components/Skills";
import Contact from "./components/Contact";
import Projects from "./components/Projects";

const { Content } = Layout;
ReactGA.initialize(Keys.GOOGLE_TRACKING_ID); //Unique Google Analytics tracking number

class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount  = () => ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
  componentDidUpdate = () => ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Layout>
            <HeaderList />
            <Content className="Content">
              <div className="RouteContent">
                <Switch>
                  <Route exact path="/" component={AboutMe} />
                  <Route path="/skills" component={Skills} />
                  <Route path="/projects" component={Projects} />
                  <Route path="/Contact" component={Contact} />
                </Switch>
              </div>
            </Content>
          </Layout>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can we put this GA code on multiple components or on a particular pages?

Comment: If you put the code on multiple components, it will work. However, it's better to write the code on the parent component and you will not need to replicate code on the other components.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately [`onUpdate` was removed in React Router v4](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4278), which means your `fireTracking` function never fires.

In the react-ga documentation [there's an example from Julia Giu](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga/wiki/React-Router-v4-withTracker) that has been included for exactly this scenario which involves wrapping your application in an HoC.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re interested in tracking page visits (and user behavior down the road), I suggest using the Segment analytics library and following our [React quickstart guide](https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-react) to track page calls using the [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/) library. You can allow the [`<Route />`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route) component to handle when the page renders and use `componentDidMount` to invoke `page` calls. The example below shows one way you could do this:

```
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Switch>
       <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
       <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

```
export default class Home extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.analytics.page('Home');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>
        Home page.
      </h1>
    );
  }
}
```

I’m the maintainer of https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-react. With Segment, you’ll be able to switch different destinations on-and-off by the flip of a switch if you are interested in trying multiple analytics tools (we support over 250+ destinations) without having to write any additional code.