# Users visits not being sent to my Analytics account

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, react-ga

I want to implement Google Analytics on my react application and I have set it up using react-ga module.

```
import ReactGA from "react-ga";
...
ReactGA.initialize('analytics-code-here');

const App = () => {

    useEffect(() => {
        ReactGA.set({ page: window.location.pathname + window.location.search});
        ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search)
    }, [])

    return (
       ...
    );
```

I have set it up two days ago, but there is no data sent to my analytics account.
How could I recieve data into Google Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

For pageview you don't need to use `set` command, just use these lines to initializing GA and tracking pageviews:

```
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
ReactGA.initialize('UA-000000-01');
ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
```

https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga

Comment: thanks you. I've removed it, but it not showing anything in my analytics account

Comment: UA code is right? Do you get some errors in console/log?

Comment: I have set debug to true in the ReactGA and it just outputs the  same function and some variables and their values but no errors

Comment: yes, it does. I tried both when I make a web only it starts with UA- and I tried it also as  web + app it doesn't but both didn't show anything

Comment: What version of react? See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49398355/google-analytics-on-react-app-doesnt-work/50289783